# How to create a token with confidential transfers and transfer fee extensions?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, rust, token-extensions

How can I create a SPL token with the both the confidential transfer and transfer fee extensions?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to include the instructions to initialize both extensions before you initialize the mint. If you're using the CLI, that would be:

```
$ spl-token create-token \
  --enable-confidential-transfers auto \
  --transfer-fee 10 11 \
  --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb
```

You can mix and match any extensions that you want in your mint!